# "Страна советов" — происхождение названия

Tags: значение-слов, названия

Может, у меня глупый вопрос, но задумался над словосочетанием "страна советов" и словом "советский". Почему вообще так страну и строй называли? О каких советах изначально шла речь?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально о Советах рабочих и крестьянских депутатов, образовавшемся в ходе ещё Февральской революции 1917 года. Были ещё Советы солдат и матросов и множество других. Это были стихийные коллегиальные органы альтернативной власти. В течение 1917 года лидирующие позиции в советах заняли представители большевиков и после Октябрьского переворота именно Советы стали единственными представителями власти. В ходе гражданской войны сторонники советов противопоставлялись монархистам и сторонникам Учредительного собрания. После победы большевиков коммунисты сохранили слово "Совет" как название для органов власти как центральных, так и на местах, а "Страна советов" стало одним из неофициальных наименований СССР.

Answer (score 2):

О советах народных депутатов. А сначала - о советах депутатов трудящихся. Советы- это 
выборные представительные органы государственной власти. Как было сказано в Конституции,  "Вся власть в СССР принадлежит трудящимся города и деревни в лице Советов депутатов трудящихся"